# Mootools/CSS height morph result.

Tags: javascript, css, mootools

I've created a shopping cart page that displays a list of all items in the cart, and each item has a button to remove the item from the cart. I'm trying to handle to removal of the item from the cart via Javascript.

The item is supposed to fade out completely, then morph the `height`, `margin` and `padding` values down to 0. However, during the second morph, the item below the removed item changes in height inverse to the size of the removed item.

Before:
[image: Before state]

After:
[image: After state]

I can't figure out for the life of me what's happening here, and why. I've checked the `DOM` elements in Firebug to see if any style is being applied to them (or their children elements), but there doesn't appear to be any change. I'm absolutely perplexed.

JSFiddle of my code: http://jsfiddle.net/9yeqs5vq/

Comment: JSFiddle version of my work has been created and added to the post. Although I don't think JSFiddle likes my Javascript as it doesn't seem to want to run at all.

Comment: I have played around with the CSS and Javascript a bit now that I have some spare time on the project, and it appears that adding an `overflow: hidden;` onto the containing box seems to correct the behavior. I will continue to fiddle around with my code until I figure out why the code acts as such, and will update when I do figure this out.

Comment: Yeah, looks like the `#gdwboutique.panier .cart .cart_item { overflow:hidden;} ` should fix it. Its not a MooTools issue but a CSS one since the height of parent is `0px` after animation but the children are still taking space. I think it could be [something like this](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/). Anyway it works with that CSS fix: http://jsfiddle.net/9yeqs5vq/2/